# Enforcing function naming conventions

Tags: python, pylint

I'd like to write a Pylint plug in which allows me to enforce some sort of syntax on the methods that are decorated with a certain decorator.

For example, all the functions that are decorated with `@specialfunction` decorator, must start with word "get_"

```
@specialfunction
def get_foo(self):
 ...


@specialfunction
def get_bar(self):
 ...
```

If my module has any methods that are decorated with `@specialfunction` but do not start with `get_`, it should throw an error. Can you please suggest how to go about writing such a pylint plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Is doing the check at runtime good enough? It's easier than writing a Pylint plugin:

```
def specialfunction(f):
    if not f.__name__[:4] == 'get_':
        raise TypeError("Can't use the decorator on a non-get function")
    return f

@specialfunction
def get_foo(x):
    return "foo"

@specialfunction  # TypeError raised here
def bar(y, z):
    return "bar"
```

This'd typically raise the error when you import the offending module.

Comment: That's an interesting way but doesn't quite serve the purpose. Thanks for the suggestion anyway :)